# Multiplying two inputted arguments within a function in Python

Tags: python, function

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

#Create a function named calculate_backup_size that takes two arguments: data and backup. 
#This function should return the data multiplied by backup, representing the total storage needed for backups in a week.

data_size_input = int(input("What is the data size? ")),
backup_frequency_input = int(input("What is the backup frequency? "))

def calculate_backup_size(data, backup):
    return data*backup

storage = calculate_backup_size(data_size_input, backup_frequency_input)
print(storage)
```

The user enters 2 numbers at the beginning and then the function will multiply those 2 inputs by the user. If you input 4 and 5 I would expect 20 (4 * 5 = 20), but instead im getting (4,4,4,4,4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an extra comma at the end of this line:

```
data_size_input = int(input("What is the data size?")),
```

which makes `data_size_input` a tuple. Just remove it and it will work fine.

Comment: Completely missed that. Thank you!